# Reshape wide to long, preserving ID variable from rownames

Tags: r, reshape2

I am trying to get the following data into long format in R:

```
testdata <- data.frame(rnorm(10),rnorm(10),rnorm(10))
rownames(testdata) <- paste0("ID",1:10) # Ids
colnames(testdata) <- c(2001,2002,2003) # Years
testdata
```

So the columns = time, the rows = IDs. Should not be too hard, but in all the examples I found it was the other way around. How can this be done in `datatable` or `reshape` or in any other of the popular dataframe packages?
Thanks for any hints. I know one way by transposing my data, but this seems to be a rather inefficient way for this purpose.

Comment: Try with `melt` `melt(as.matrix(testdata))` or with `tidyverse` `rownames_to_column(testdata, 'rn') %>% gather(key, val, -rn)`

Comment: @akrun thanks e.g. `melt(as.matrix(testdata))` works. But why do I need to convert into a matrix? Seems also kind of inefficient to me, because then obviously I have to reconvert right away into datatable. But if that's the way to go, I will do it.

Comment: Because it will drop the row name as a column.  If efficiency is the case, create a column of rownames before doing the `melt`. i.e. `setDT(testdata, keep.rownames = TRUE)` and then use `melt`

Comment: in base R you could do the same with: `data.frame(as.table(as.matrix(testdata)))` or even `cbind(ID=rownames(testdata),stack(testdata))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to turn [akrun's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51794875/reshape-wide-to-long-preserving-id-variable-from-rownames#comment90547357_51794875) into a complete answer:

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(testdata, keep.rownames = TRUE), "rn")
```

> ```
>       rn variable       value
>  1:  ID1     2001 -0.25265860
>  2:  ID2     2001  0.50538399
>  3:  ID3     2001  0.68216394
>  4:  ID4     2001  0.62203871
>  5:  ID5     2001  0.59297019
>  6:  ID6     2001  0.69383842
>  7:  ID7     2001  1.77900432
>  8:  ID8     2001 -1.69010623
>  9:  ID9     2001 -2.17762905
> 10: ID10     2001  0.61463127
> 11:  ID1     2002  0.42120060
> 12:  ID2     2002 -0.16148732
> ...
> ```

Comment: thanks, this was fastest in the comments above. I believe what is missing is setting the key of the resulting DT to `rn,variable`, as that is the usually desired format

Answer (score 5):

**@Akron's useful answer:**

```
reshape2::melt(as.matrix(testdata))
```

**The "But Why?" part:**

You have important information in your rownames, which is *not* usually a good place to store important information. We need that information when we reshape. The question becomes then, why does `melt` use that information if we feed in a matrix but not a dataframe?

The reason is that `melt` is a generic function that dispatches a method (aka a more-specific function) based on the type of data you feed into it.  So if `m` is a matrix and you call `melt(m)`, then R is actually executing `melt.matrix(m)`.  Conversely, if `df` is a dataframe and you call `melt(df)`, then R is actually executing `melt.data.frame(df)`. These two functions -- `melt.matrix()` and `melt.data.frame()` -- handle rownames differently; The method `melt.matrix` uses those rownames the way you want, whereas the method `melt.data.frame` does not.  So, in order to get your desired output, you need to feed a matrix (not a dataframe) into `melt`.

Just to demonstrate, if we had the ID information stored in a column of our data.frame (as in `testdata2` below) instead of as rownames (as in `testdata` above), then we're good-to-go in terms of feeding in a dataframe to `melt`:

```
testdata2 <- data.frame(
    ID       =  1:10,
    year2001 = rnorm(10),
    year2002 = rnorm(10),
    year2003 = rnorm(10) )

reshape2::melt(testdata2, "ID")
reshape2::melt(testdata2, id.vars="ID", measure.vars=2:4) #equivalently, but verbosely
```

Comment: Thanks I upvoted your answer. What I dont understand is why rownames are not eligible to store important information. Because if they dont, why do they even exist?

Comment: R has been continually developed since the 1970's, so the "why does such-and-such exist" is usually a long and detailed story that almost always ends with "we would change it today, but for backward-compatibility reasons, we won't."

Comment: Specifically with regard to rownames, I side with Hadley Wickham who believes that "generally, it is best to avoid row names, because they are basically a character column with different semantics to every other column." However, see [this post](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/272) for an opposing viewpoint.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious hack to me seems to be to augment the dataframe's rownames back to a regular column; then you can use whichever of `reshape/reshape2/tidyr::gather`

```
> data.frame(ID=rownames(testdata), testdata, row.names=NULL)
     ID      X2001      X2002       X2003
1   ID1  0.6714540  1.1516917  0.51332801
2   ID2 -1.7309721 -1.8018835  1.54385452
3   ID3 -0.4831349 -1.3965915 -0.72819988
4   ID4  1.2591651  1.2436120  1.01472455
5   ID5  1.2346326 -1.4587475 -1.75097483
6   ID6  0.4279562  0.2595588  1.36560258
7   ID7  0.9990642 -1.0306002 -1.10165672
8   ID8  1.2118510 -0.3577358 -0.11696953
9   ID9  0.3074985  0.5177188 -0.09954961
10 ID10 -1.0418608 -1.8419336 -0.65401215
```

(Note it "fixed" your illegal colnames to 'X2001','X2002'... if you really want to keep them, use `...check.names=FALSE)`)

Answer (score 0):

you can use tidyr library

```
library(tidyr)
cbind(paste0("ID",1:10), gather(testdata, "years", "value"))
```

Comment: This throws away the ID variable from rownames, which was the OP's question